# Changelog of deb package

Tags: debian, deb

I'm using `dpkg -b` to build packages with python scripts. (DEBIAN format).

In the DEBIAN folder I'have added the following files:

```
compat
control
copyright
changelog
```

The changelog is using the right format.

```
7zrecover (1.0-1) UNRELEASED; urgency=low

  * Initial release. (Closes: #XXXXXX)

 -- Lars Wirzenius <liw@liw.fi>  Thu, 18 Nov 2010 17:25:32 +0000
```

When I install the package, and I try to display the changelog, I always get

```
This change is not coming from a source that supports changelogs.

Failed to fetch the changelog for 7zrecover
URI was: http:/// . changelog
```

(the URI is .///. Changelog, the site does not let me post it right)

"This change is not coming from a source that supports changelogs." is there anyway to fix this?

I was thinking in redirect the source to the computer, and putting a changelog at /usr/share/doc/7zrecover/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This change is not coming from a source that supports changelogs. is there anyway to fix this?

You need to upload your package to a repository. Locally installed packages don't offer this structure. If you want to check the changelog of a locally created package, you need to check the `/usr/share/doc/<package>/changelog.Debian.gz` files. That's where it get stored locally.

According to [the Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-docs.html#s-changelogs):

> Packages that are not Debian-native must contain a compressed copy of the `debian/changelog` file from the Debian source tree in `/usr/share/doc/package` with the name `changelog.Debian.gz`.

So, if your package doesn't have it, then there's something wrong with the way you created your package, since dpkg-buildpackage follow this.

Comment: I was checking this but i don't have the file. Do i have to manually add a `changelog.Debian.gz`? I actually was adding the changelog as text file at `/usr/share/doc/package/`

Comment: @rsm If you use `dpkg -b`, you need to do everything manually. You shouldn't use `dpkg -b`, it's only meant to be called by higher-level programs. Use `dpkg-buildpackage` to build the binary package from a properly-formed source package. You can use `dh_make` to populate the source tree with a template for the Debian part of the source package (the `debian` directory).

Comment: @Gilles i know that `dpkg-buildpackage` is much more recommended but i haven't managed to create a package with that tool. I only build packages from python and bash scripts and i don't understand why i need to create the tar.gz folder. Also i don't know how to create a `makefile` that does nothing. I'll possibly ask the question but i wanted to try it some more times. For the moment I'm using this builder that i created [deb-builder](http://rsm.imap.cc/GNU-Linux#deb-builder)